# Python non blocking async log compression and separate file rotation

Tags: python, logging

I am new to python but getting very much upset about python logger. It looks like there is no solid logging implementation. I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Log and rotate file on hourly basis into separate directories and files e.g 2017/12/28/ - 24 hourly files .log in that directory
2. Gzip files automatically
3. Non-blocking, async logger. (Latency is very important)

I am new to python and something that I have managed to produce seems like not a right way to go. Could you please recommend a better approach or refactor my solution if you think it is decent.

```
import logging
import queue
import gzip
import os

from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener, TimedRotatingFileHandler


class GZipRotator:
    def __call__(self, source, dest):

        dir_parts = dest.split('.log.')
        date_dir = dir_parts[1].replace('-', '/').replace('_', '/')
        new_dir = os.path.join(dir_parts[0], date_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
            os.makedirs(new_dir)

        new_full_file_name = os.path.join(new_dir, dest.split('/')[-1])
        os.rename(source, new_full_file_name)
        f_in = open(new_full_file_name, 'rb')
        f_out = gzip.open("%s.gz" % new_full_file_name, 'wb')
        f_out.writelines(f_in)
        f_out.close()
        f_in.close()
        os.remove(new_full_file_name)


def setup_logger(log_name, level=logging.INFO):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    que = queue.Queue(-1)  # no limit on size
    queue_handler = QueueHandler(que)

    log_file_dir = os.path.join('logs', log_name)
    __create_log_dir(log_file_dir)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler("%s.log" % log_file_dir, when='h', interval=1, delay=False, utc=True)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.rotator = GZipRotator()

    listener = QueueListener(que, handler)

    root = logging.getLogger(log_name)
    root.addHandler(queue_handler)
    root.setLevel(level)

    listener.start()


def __create_log_dir(dir):
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)

setup_logger('orders')
logger = logging.getLogger('orders')
while True:
   logger.info('123')
```

Comment: Why are you using a `__call__` in a class instead of a function?